# How to break a line within a quotation in Rmarkdown title

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Using R and knitr, I want to break a title into two lines.  I used to be able to do this with "\n", but this is not working now.

```
---
title: "DeKAF Cross Sectional Study:\nAnalysis of ptc, C4d, and DSA"

author: "L.G. Hunsicker"

date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y")`'
output: 
  pdf_document:  
  fig_width: 6
  fig_height: 4
  keep_tex:  true
---
```

produces:

```
DeKAF Cross Sectional Study Analysis of ptc, C4d, and
DSA

L.G. Hunsicker

27 August, 2017
```

Any idea how to split a quoted line now?
Larry Hunsicker

Comment: do you have a space between the `:` and the `\n`?

Comment: Just gave this link a try and it works for me.

Comment: The solution given in the link above works for me.   
Two spaces before the pipe (|), one after, with no quotation marks, works now for me. – Larry Hunsicker 1 min ago   edit